# Compiler Error. Expected ';' Before Token

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

```
//this application implements use of a simple set
//program does data insertion,searching, and deletion
//program will represent a set of keys
//a user can add a key, delete a key, and check for duplicate keys
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string key, answer,answer2;
int i;

std::set<std::string> Keyring;

//prompts user to insert elements in set
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
cout<<"\nInsert Key " <<i+1<<" Onto Key Ring. Use _ For Spaces"<<endl;
cin >>key;
Keyring.insert(key);

}
//shows resulting key ring
cout<<"\nHere is Completed Key Ring\n"<<endl;
for(std::set<std::string>::iterator it=Keyring.begin(); it !=Keyring.end(); it++) //the '<' operator keeps UNIQUE elements in sorted order
{
std::cout<<" "<<"\n"<< *it; 
}


//Set Deletion and Addition
cout<<"\nWould You Like to Add or Delete From Key Ring?"<<endl;
cout<<"\nType add or delete"<<endl;
cin>>answer;

if(answer=="add")
{
cout<<"\nAdd Another Key. Use _ For Spaces"<<endl;
cin>>key;
Keyring.insert(key);

    if(Keyring.insert(key).second) //checks to see if key already present in set
    {
    cout<<key<<" Successful Addition!"<<endl;
    }   
    else if(!Keyring.insert(key).second)
    {
    cout<<" Duplicate Key Can't Be Added!"<<endl;
    }
}
else(answer=="delete")
{
cout<<"\nDelete A Key. Use _ For Spaces"<<endl;
cin>>key;
Keyring.erase(key);
cout<<"\nNew Keyring"<<endl;
}

for(std::set<std::string>::iterator it=Keyring.begin(); it !=Keyring.end(); it++)
{
std::cout<<" "<<"\n"<< *it;
}
cout<<"\nKeyring size is "<<Keyring.size()<<endl;

//Set Searching
cout<<"\nWant To Search For A Key y/n?"<<endl;
cin>>answer2;

if(answer2=="y")
{
cout<<"\nSearch For A Key. Use _ For Spaces"<<endl;
cout<<"\nWhere Is My..."<<endl;
cin>>key; cout<<" Key?"<<endl;
}
std::set<std::string>::iterator it=Keyring.find(key);

if(it !=Keyring.end())
{
cout<<key<<"\nFound!"<<endl;
}
else
{
cout<<key<<"\nNot Found :("<<endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

I can't run my program because of this error:[Error] expected ';' before '{' token. The problem starts in the 'Set Addition and Deletion' portion. The problem is with the big If-Else statement in that section, on line where the else statement starts. I've been looking over this for an hour now and it sooo frustrating! The compiler's saying that there should be a ';' before the 'else' statement line but everything looks fine syntax-wise. I checked documentation for nested if-statements so I could avoid this problem. Help needed!

Comment: `else(answer=="delete")` looks suspicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`else(answer=="delete")` should be `else if(answer=="delete")`, C++ does not have any special `elif` form so you need to start a new `if` block after `else` if you want to check another condition.

It is also a good idea to write literal on the left side of comparison operator like `("delete" == answer)`, this way you can easily detect accidental assignment typos.

Comment: I usually don't use complex if statements like this. When it gets complicated, always switch statements. Just couldn't see how I could use them in this program. Oh well maybe next time and thanks.